"+" Button Not Clickable When Aligned with Drawer Button in React Native
I'm experiencing an issue with a "+" button in a React Native layout using NativeBase and Expo. The goal of this button is to navigate to another screen when clicked, but it's not working when aligned horizontally with the Drawer button in the header. It only becomes clickable if I add a top margin (mt={5}) to the container that contais the button, which misaligns it from the Drawer button's row.
What I'm Trying to Do:
I have a screen called MyDrivers that displays a list of drivers. In the header, there’s a menu (Drawer) button on the left and a container that contains the "+" button on the right for adding a new driver. When the "+" button is clicked, it should navigate to the driver registration screen.
The Problem:
When the "+" button container is horizontally aligned with the Drawer button, it becomes unclickable.
If I add marginTop={5} to the container that contains the "+" button, misaligning it vertically from the Drawer button, it becomes clickable.
Attempts to Fix:
Below are code snippets and images to illustrate the problem and the workaround:
Code When Not Functional (Unclickable "+" Button) with mt={-5} in the continer:
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Avatar, VStack, HStack, Text, Button, Image } from 'native-base'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import sandRocksIcon from '@assets/areiaepedras-icon.png'
import { t } from 'i18next'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { AppStackNavigatorRoutesProps } from '@routes/app.routes'

export function MyDrivers() {
  // Fake data for drivers
  const drivers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Yura',
      car: 'TATA - Laranja',
      licensePlate: 'ABB-111-MP',
      status: 'Online',
      truckIcon: sandRocksIcon,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Alberto João',
      car: 'Funcargo - Azul',
      licensePlate: 'AAS-545-MC',
      status: 'Offline',
      truckIcon: sandRocksIcon,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Olivia da Gloria',
      car: 'Toyota - Verde',
      licensePlate: 'aaa111',
      status: 'Offline',
      truckIcon: sandRocksIcon,
    },
  ]

  const navigation = useNavigation<AppStackNavigatorRoutesProps>()

  function handleOpenRegisterDriver() {
    navigation.navigate('registerDriver')
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <VStack safeArea p="" w="100%" mx="auto" bg="background">
        <Box bg="red.700" padding={6}> 
          
           //The container(HStack) that contains my + button
          <HStack
            ml={10}
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            mt={-5} //The margin top
          >
            <Text color="white" fontSize="lg" marginLeft={10}>
              {t('My Drivers')}
            </Text>
             
            // The + button
            <Button
              variant="ghost"
              colorScheme="white"
              onPress={handleOpenRegisterDriver}
            >
              <Ionicons name="add" color="white" size={24} />
            </Button>
          </HStack>
        </Box>

        <VStack space={2} mt={4}>
          {drivers.map((driver) => (
            <Box
              key={driver.id}
              px={4}
              py={2}
              bg="white"
              borderRadius={10}
              mx={4}
              my={1}
              shadow={2}
            >
              <HStack justifyContent="space-between">
                <HStack space={2} alignItems="center">
                  <Avatar
                    size="xl"
                    source={{ uri: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150' }}
                    borderColor="red.500"
                    borderWidth={2}
                  />

                  <Box>
                    <Text color="gray.500" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="md">
                      {driver.name}
                    </Text>

                    <Text color="gray.500" _dark={{ color: 'warmGray.200' }}>
                      {driver.car}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      color="coolGray.600"
                      _dark={{ color: 'warmGray.200' }}
                    >
                      {driver.licensePlate}
                    </Text>

                    <HStack alignItems="center" space={1} mt={2}>
                      <Box
                        h={3}
                        w={3}
                        borderRadius="full"
                        bg={
                          driver.status === 'Online' ? 'green.600' : 'gray.500'
                        }
                      />
                      <Text fontFamily="body" color="gray.500">
                        {driver.status}
                      </Text>
                    </HStack>
                  </Box>
                </HStack>

                <Image
                  source={driver.truckIcon}
                  alt={t('Ícone de Areia e Pedras')}
                  width={10}
                  height={10}
                  mt={20}
                />
              </HStack>
            </Box>
          ))}
        </VStack>
      </VStack>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

Image with Non-clickable "+" Button When Aligned:

Functional Code (With mt={5}, But Misaligned):
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Avatar, VStack, HStack, Text, Button, Image } from 'native-base'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import sandRocksIcon from '@assets/areiaepedras-icon.png'
import { t } from 'i18next'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { AppStackNavigatorRoutesProps } from '@routes/app.routes'

export function MyDrivers() {
  // Fake data for drivers
  const drivers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Yura',
      car: 'TATA - Laranja',
      licensePlate: 'ABB-111-MP',
      status: 'Online',
      truckIcon: sandRocksIcon,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Alberto João',
      car: 'Funcargo - Azul',
      licensePlate: 'AAS-545-MC',
      status: 'Offline',
      truckIcon: sandRocksIcon,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Olivia da Gloria',
      car: 'Toyota - Verde',
      licensePlate: 'aaa111',
      status: 'Offline',
      truckIcon: sandRocksIcon,
    },
  ]

  const navigation = useNavigation<AppStackNavigatorRoutesProps>()

  function handleOpenRegisterDriver() {
    navigation.navigate('registerDriver')
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <VStack safeArea p="" w="100%" mx="auto" bg="background">
        <Box bg="red.700" padding={6}>

           //The container(HStack) that contains my + button
          <HStack
            ml={10}
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            mt={5} //the margin top
          >
            <Text color="white" fontSize="lg" marginLeft={10}>
              {t('My Drivers')}
            </Text>

            //The + button
            <Button
              variant="ghost"
              colorScheme="white"
              onPress={handleOpenRegisterDriver}
            >
              <Ionicons name="add" color="white" size={24} />
            </Button>
          </HStack>
        </Box>

        <VStack space={2} mt={4}>
          {drivers.map((driver) => (
            <Box
              key={driver.id}
              px={4}
              py={2}
              bg="white"
              borderRadius={10}
              mx={4}
              my={1}
              shadow={2}
            >
              <HStack justifyContent="space-between">
                <HStack space={2} alignItems="center">
                  <Avatar
                    size="xl"
                    source={{ uri: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150' }}
                    borderColor="red.500"
                    borderWidth={2}
                  />

                  <Box>
                    <Text color="gray.500" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="md">
                      {driver.name}
                    </Text>

                    <Text color="gray.500" _dark={{ color: 'warmGray.200' }}>
                      {driver.car}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      color="coolGray.600"
                      _dark={{ color: 'warmGray.200' }}
                    >
                      {driver.licensePlate}
                    </Text>

                    <HStack alignItems="center" space={1} mt={2}>
                      <Box
                        h={3}
                        w={3}
                        borderRadius="full"
                        bg={
                          driver.status === 'Online' ? 'green.600' : 'gray.500'
                        }
                      />
                      <Text fontFamily="body" color="gray.500">
                        {driver.status}
                      </Text>
                    </HStack>
                  </Box>
                </HStack>

                <Image
                  source={driver.truckIcon}
                  alt={t('Ícone de Areia e Pedras')}
                  width={10}
                  height={10}
                  mt={20}
                />
              </HStack>
            </Box>
          ))}
        </VStack>
      </VStack>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

Image with Clickable "+" Button but Misaligned:

This code defines a navigation structure for my application using both a Drawer Navigator and a Stack Navigator:
import React from 'react'
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerNavigationProp,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import {
  createNativeStackNavigator,
  NativeStackNavigationProp,
} from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { Home } from '@screens/Home'
import { IconButton } from 'react-native-paper'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Requisition } from '@screens/Requisition'
import { ContactUs } from '@screens/ContactUs'
import { DriverDetails } from '@screens/DriverDetails'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { MyDrivers } from '@screens/MyDrivers'
import { Profile } from '@screens/Profile'
import { RegisterDriver } from '@screens/RegisterDriver'
import { RideHistory } from '@screens/RideHistory'
import { RideDetails } from '@screens/RideDetails'
import { Notifications } from '@screens/Notifications'
import { DrawerContent } from '@components/DrawerContent'
import { Image } from 'native-base'

import requistionIcon from '@assets/request.png'
import raceIcon from '@assets/race.png'
import profileIcon from '@assets/profile.png'
import homeIcon from '@assets/home.png'
import contactIcon from '@assets/contact.png'
import driverIcon from '@assets/driver.png'
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { AllocateDriver } from '@screens/AllocateDriver'

type AppDrawerRoutes = {
  home: undefined
  requisition: undefined
  rideHistory: undefined
  myDrivers: undefined
  contactUS: undefined
  profile: undefined
  notifications: undefined
}

type AppStackRoutes = {
  drawerRoutes: undefined
  driverDetails: undefined
  registerDriver: undefined
  rideDetails: undefined
  allocateDriver: undefined
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<AppDrawerRoutes>()
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<AppStackRoutes>()

// Drawer Navigator
function DrawerRoutesComponent() {
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        headerShown: true,
        headerTitle: '',
        headerTransparent: true,

        //The drawer button
        headerLeft: () => (
          <View style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
            <IconButton
              icon="menu"
              onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              iconColor={route.name === 'home' ? 'black' : 'white'}
            />
          </View>
        ),
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        drawerActiveTintColor: '#f00',
        drawerStyle: {
          marginTop: -32,
        },
        drawerInactiveTintColor: '#000',
        drawerLabelStyle: { marginLeft: -15 },
      })}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => <Image source={homeIcon} w={6} h={6} alt="home" />,
          drawerLabel: t('Home'),
        }}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="requisition"
        component={Requisition}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={requistionIcon} w={6} h={6} alt="requisition" />
          ),
          drawerLabel: t('Requisition'),
        }}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="rideHistory"
        component={RideHistory}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={raceIcon} w={6} h={6} alt="ride history" />
          ),
          drawerLabel: t('Ride History'),
        }}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="myDrivers"
        component={MyDrivers}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={driverIcon} w={6} h={6} alt="my drivers" />
          ),
          drawerLabel: t('My Drivers'),
        }}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="contactUS"
        component={ContactUs}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={contactIcon} w={6} h={6} alt="contact us" />
          ),
          drawerLabel: t('Contact Us'),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={profileIcon} w={6} h={6} alt="profile" />
          ),
          drawerLabel: t('Profile'),
        }}
      />

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <MaterialIcons name="notifications-none" size={24} />
          ),
          drawerLabel: t('Notifications'),
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

// Stack Navigator
export function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="drawerRoutes" component={DrawerRoutesComponent} />
      <Stack.Screen name="driverDetails" component={DriverDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen name="registerDriver" component={RegisterDriver} />
      <Stack.Screen name="rideDetails" component={RideDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen name="allocateDriver" component={AllocateDriver} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

// Export the navigation props types
export type AppDrawerNavigatorRoutesProps =
  DrawerNavigationProp<AppDrawerRoutes>
export type AppStackNavigatorRoutesProps =
  NativeStackNavigationProp<AppStackRoutes>

Attempts to Fix:
I added zIndex={1} to the "+" button contianer, but this didn't resolve the issue. The button is still unresponsive when aligned with the Drawer button.
I tried using position="absolute" and adjusting right to position the "+" button to the right, but that didn't work either.
Question
Why is the "+" button not clickable when aligned with the Drawer button, and how can I resolve this while keeping the alignment intact?
